# Pillow not recognising any of its save formats

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am currently trying to use a python file downloaded from GitHub to understand how it works. It picks up system camera inputs as well as the display using pyscreenshot and allows these to be used from a webpage. Everytime I run it I encounter this error message when a user connects to the webpage.

```
    save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()]
KeyError: 'PNG'
```

Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera
import pyscreenshot
import flask
from PIL import ImageGrab
import PIL
from io import BytesIO
import socket

app = Flask(__name__)

print(PIL.PILLOW_VERSION)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/screen.png')
def serve_pil_image():
    img_buffer = BytesIO()
    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    img.save(img_buffer, format = 'PNG', quality=10)
    img_buffer.seek(0)
    return flask.send_file(img_buffer, mimetype='image/png')


@app.route('/js/<path:path>')
def send_js(path):
    return flask.send_from_directory('js', path)


@app.route('/css/<path:path>')
def send_css(path):
    return flask.send_from_directory('css', path)


def get_ip():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        # doesn't even have to be reachable
        s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
        IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    except:
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    return IP


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=get_ip(), debug=False)
```

I can't seem to find any useful information on why the error is being thrown. I am using Windows 10 and python 3.8.2

Update:

After running a smaller version of this focusing on what I thought the issue was, it shows a screenshot but as a PNG and not JPEG.

Here is the smaller version of the code:

```
import pyscreenshot
from PIL import ImageGrab
import PIL
from io import BytesIO

img_buffer = BytesIO()
img = ImageGrab.grab()
img.save(img_buffer, format = 'JPEG', quality=10)
img_buffer.seek(0)

img.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried reproducing this bug in a more stripped-down form? For instance, it's unlikely your error has anything to do with Flask. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also when you say "any of its save formats"—have you tried other formats besides PNG? If so, which ones?

Comment: I have tried TIFF and JPEG, in the exact same format as above and the same issue occurs.

Comment: All three of those require support libraries to be installed when Pillow is built, if you build it from source. Have you tried anything else, like say GIF or BMP?

Comment: I have just tried those formats and the issue is still there. I will try installing the support libraries for the other formats and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, turned out to be incorrect MIME settings along with the lack of support libraries.

Comment: Note that `img.show()` will save the image again to a temporary file, it won't show the one you saved earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to a format that does not need a support library and checking that the MIME is set to 'image/gif' or whatever format.

Installing the support libraries for the other formats now.